# I have followed the Adafruit Tutorial for using the LED matrix Backpack But Get "No module named Image" error

Tags: python

I have followed the instructions here:
https://learn.adafruit.com/led-backpack-displays-on-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/usage
They have not worked and when I try to run the test python script I got an error about not having the module Image which I fixed by putting "from PIL" before the "import Image". However there is still an import statement that needs fixing in the directory: "build/bdist.linux-armv61/egg/Adafruit_LED_Backpack/Matrix8x8.py"

I cannot get to this file though...
Is there any way of editing this file as I have failed in doing so from the command line and from the File Manager

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If it is a system file you need privileges -- try `sudoedit`.